# How to replace with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace string `X.Y.Z[X.Y.Z]` to `X_Y_Z[X_Y_Z]` from my string. So I am using regex where first I am escaping. `escapeRegExp` is working fine but `replaceAll` is not replacing.

https://jsfiddle.net/txp9mecs/1/

```
let main = "X.Y.Z[X.Y.Z]";

function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}

function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp("\\b" + escapeRegExp(find) + "\\b", "g"), replace);
}

console.log(replaceAll("dfs X.Y.Z[X.Y.Z] dfs", main, "X_Y_Z[X_Y_Z]"))
```

Does anyone know what I am doing here ?

Comment: `"X.Y.Z[X.Y.Z]".replace(/\./g, '_')` You mean like that?

Comment: Before replace I want to escape all special characters not only `.`

Comment: Use `pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\W)" + escapeRegExp(find) + "(?!\\w)");` and then instead of `replace`, `"$1" + replace(/\$/g, "$$$$")`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I didn't get you . can you write snippet ? I am trying `function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
  const pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\W)" + escapeRegExp(find) + "(?!\\w)");
  return str.replace("$1" + replace(/\$/g, "$$$$"), replace);
}`

Comment: I meant `replace.replace(/\$/g, "$$$$")`... See https://jsfiddle.net/no97hn2g/

Comment: thank you so much :) it worked